# apache error log backup auto

Tags: apache, logging, backup

This is my first question. I don't know how to config error.log has 2 function as below:

1. The log generated by current day will output to one fixed name log file. e.g error.log. This current log contains  the current generated log only.
2. The previous log will back-up to single log file. e.g:
   yesterday is 11/22/2013, so the error log of yesterday is named 11_22_2013.error.log

Comment: Could you clarify what is going wrong or what you're having trouble understanding?

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of the *rotatelogs* command to log rotate the apache logs. Try to put the following as a crontab.

```
crontab -e
```

Add the following there.

```
/usr/local/apache/bin/rotatelogs /path_to_apachelogs.%Y.%m.%d 86400
```

*/usr/local/apache/bin/rotatelogs* This path is meant for a cPanel server. You needed to give the full path for it to work. You can use the following command for getting the path.

```
which rotatelogs
```

If this is not showing any outputs, Try to locate the path with the *locate* command.

You can have further awareness from the following [link](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/programs/rotatelogs.html)